# IE 6 JQuery toggle class bug! Help!

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

While developing a new site I stop periodically and test all new functionality in IE6.  It's a pain but we can't drop support yet.

I have hit a problem with JQuerys toogleClass function.  I have a css styled `<button>` that toggles between a plus and a minus image when clicked.  This works on all browsers expect IE6.

```
$('#searchForm #toggleButton').toggleClass('more');
$('#searchForm #toggleButton').toggleClass('less');
alert($('#toggleButton').attr('class')); <--- This displays 'less'
```

When first rendered the button displays the correct image.  When clicked the image and all the css styles disappear.  The class 'more' is removed but the class 'less' isn't applied.  Placing an alert box to debug shows that JQuery thinks the 'less' class has been set properly but the browser hasn't applied it.

I have tried using different tags such as a `<div>` but the same problem persists.

Any help welcome

**EDIT** Added HTML and CSS

HTML

```
...
<div id="search-panel">
    <form action="/Search" class="search" id="searchForm" method="post"> 
    ...
        <div class="buttons">   
            <button type="submit" id="searchButton"></button>  
            <div class="loading"></div>  
            <button type="button" id="toggleButton" class="more"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
...
</div>
...
```

CSS

```
#search-panel .buttons #toggleButton.more { width:13px; height:13px; clear:both; float:right; margin:5px 3px 0 0; background:url(../Images/button-search-toggle.png) no-repeat 0 -13px;  }
#search-panel .buttons #toggleButton.less { width:13px; height:13px; clear:both; float:right; margin:5px 3px 0 0; background:url(../Images/button-search-toggle.png) no-repeat;  }
```

Comment: It sounds like your CSS is the issue here, can you post it and the markup?

Comment: Ok will do, however the css renders correctly on all other browsers.

Comment: @Dominic - That rarely means much when talking about IE6 errors though :)

Comment: @Nick - Good point.  Posted what html and css I though was relevant.

Comment: @Dominic - Do you have multiple `id="toggleButton"` elements in the page?

Comment: @Nick - No just the one #toggleButton, my jquery selector was simplified for this example.  Will update it to match what I have.

Comment: Try using !important on the background property.

Comment: @Dominic - Try using *only* `#toggleButton` for both the jQuery and the CSS...also you can pass both classes to toggle to switch between them: `$('#toggleButton').toggleClass('more less');`

Comment: @Nick - Cheers for the pointer `$('#toggleButton').toggleClass('more less');`.  Using only `#toggleButton` didn't work.

Comment: @John - Sorry that doesn't work.  It's not applying any off the css, not just the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 doesn't understand chaining CSS like:

```
div.class1.class2
```

Change your CSS to:

```
#search-panel .buttons .more { width:13px; height:13px; clear:both; float:right; margin:5px 3px 0 0; background:url(../Images/button-search-toggle.png) no-repeat 0 -13px;  }
#search-panel .buttons .less { width:13px; height:13px; clear:both; float:right; margin:5px 3px 0 0; background:url(../Images/button-search-toggle.png) no-repeat;
```

And this will work

Comment: Awesome, cheers.  Odd that it can handle the chaining on the first render but not when manipulating the DOM via JavaScript. Then again it is IE 6 where odd is normal.  Anyway thanks for this as it fixed my problem.

Comment: I gave up a long time ago trying to understand why ie6 does what it does :D

Answer (score 0):

> .toggleClass( className )
>
> classNameOne or more class names
>   (separated by spaces) to be toggled
>   for each element in the matched set.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Shouldn't you code be like this :

```
$('#toggleButton').toggleClass('more less');
```

Comment: Yes but that doesn't fix the bug.

Comment: And with `$("#toggleButton").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("more less");
    });` ? I'm sorry I don't have access to IE6 here.